# Meteor mongodb version

Tags: mongodb, meteor

On starting meteor 1.4.1, I get this message:

> Your development database is using mmapv1, the old, pre-MongoDB 3.0 database
>   engine. You should consider upgrading to Wired Tiger, the new engine. The
>   easiest way to do so in development is to run meteor reset. If you'd like to
>   migrate your database, please consult
>   https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

I though Meteor looks after the mongodb side of things under the hood and I would need to fix it if it is not broken, Will it be a problem if left as is or should be better to upgrade, and how to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in here. 
https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#update-to-mongo-3_2

MDG recommended you to update. minimum version supported by metetor1.4 is Mongodb Version 2.6.